# Magento 2 | customer grid error

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-grid

I added a custom customer attribute to the `customer_grid` and now it displays following error:

> Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have
>   restored the filter to its original state.

How can I fix that?

`exception.log` shows following error:

> LIMIT 20 {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mediabasenummer' in 'order clause', query was: `` SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `customer_grid_flat` AS `main_table` WHERE (MATCH(`main_table`.name,`main_table`.email,`main_table`.created_in,`main_table`.taxvat,`main_table`.shipping_full,`main_table`.billing_full,`main_table`.billing_firstname,`main_table`.billing_lastname,`main_table`.billing_telephone,`main_table`.billing_postcode,`main_table`.billing_region,`main_table`.billing_city,`main_table`.billing_fax,`main_table`.billing_company) AGAINST('Leon')) ORDER BY mediabasenummer ASC ``

Comment: Check error in log file or try with developer mode.

Comment: I am in developer-mode

Comment: check my update please!

Comment: check column : "mediabasenummer" come from which module, you can use grep command to find string in directory in servre.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the plugin in for **mediabasenummer** column in Uicomponent data provider reporting file. You can do same as given below

1.create di.xml file `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/adminhtml` and put below code in it.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting">
        <plugin name="customer_grid_collection" type="\Namespace\Modulename\Model\Plugin\ResourceModel\Customer\Grid"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2.Create plugin model file `Grid.php` under `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Plugin/ResourceModel/Customer` and put below code in it.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\ResourceModel\Customer;
 
class Grid
{
    public static $table = 'customer_grid_flat';
    public static $leftJoinTable = 'customer_entity_int';
 
    public function afterSearch($intercepter, $collection)
    {
        $attribute_id = '180'; //mediabasenummer attribute id

        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$table)) {
            $leftJoinTableName = $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$leftJoinTable);
 
            $collection
                ->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(
                    ['cei'=>$leftJoinTableName],
                    "cei.entity_id = main_table.entity_id AND cei.attribute_id='".$attribute_id."'",
                    [
                        'mediabasenummer' => 'cei.value'
                    ]
                );
 
            $where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
            $collection->getSelect()->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE, $where)->group('main_table.entity_id');
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Perfect answer!!! +1 made my day :)